# parse json for GWT SuggestBox

Tags: json, gwt, getjson, gwt2

I want to parse a json response in Java and add its values to a suggestBox in GWT. It would be great if anyone can help me with a sample code.

```
["abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqr","acb","dfe","gih","jlk","mon"]

public void parseResponse(String str){

    MultiWordSuggestOracle oracle = new MultiWordSuggestOracle();

    JSONValue jsonValue = JSONParser.parseLenient(str);
    JSONArray jArray = jsonValue.isArray();     

    for(int i=0; i<jArray.size(); i++){

    String companySymbol = jArray.get(i).isString().toString();
    oracle.add(companySymbol);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use MultiWordSuggestOracle: you have to extend http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestOracle.html

(and its callback)

ex:

```
class MySuggestOrc extends SuggestOracle {
  public void requestSuggestions(final SuggestOracle.Request request, final SuggestOracle.Callback callback) {
    Receiver<YourJsonContainer> receiver = new Receiver<YourJsonContainer>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(YourJsonContainer companiesJsonHolder) {
        List<Suggestion> companies = //... the code to split json
        SuggestOracle.Response response = new SuggestOracle.Response();
        response.setSuggestions(companies)
        callback.onSuggestionsReady( request, response );
      }
    }
    AsyncRequest req = // get you json respons here and use ... 
  }
}
```